# Ambiguous java hierarchy

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

My question is why `x.proc(z)` below does print 57 instead of printing 39 ?

```
class X
{
    protected int v=0;
    public X() {v+=10; System.out.println("constr X");}
    public void proc(X p) {System.out.println(43);}
}

class Y extends X
{
    public Y() {v+=5;System.out.println("constr Y");}
    public void proc(X p) {System.out.println(57);}
    public int getV() {return v;}
}

class Z extends Y
{
    public Z() {v+=9;System.out.println("constr Z");}
    public void proc(Z p) {System.out.println(39);}
}

class Main
{
    public static void main(String argv[])
    {
        X x = new Z(); // v=24
        Y y = new Z(); // v=24
        Z z = new Z(); // v=24

        x.proc(z); //57
    }
}
```

`X x` refers to a `Z` object, and class `Z` does have the method `proc(Z p)` but it also has the method `proc(X p)`. Also the parameter `z` is of type `Z` so it would be reasonable to print 39.

Answer (score 1):

The method

```
public void proc(Z p) {System.out.println(39);}
```

in `Z` does not override

```
public void proc(X p) {System.out.println(43);}
```

in `X` because it restricts the domain to `Z` instead of `X`.

However, the analogous method in `Y` *does* override `proc` in `X`.

Since the compile time type of `x` is `X`, the only method signature that 
matches `x.proc(z)` is that of `public void proc(X p)`. Only now does the dynamic dispatch take place, and the overriding version from `Y` is selected and executed, which results in output "57", as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First, the compiler chooses which method (with signature) to call at compile time first.  With method resolution on which signature to call, the compile-time type of the variable is considered; polymorphism doesn't apply here.  The compile-time type of `x` is `X`, even if it really is a `Z` object at runtime.  Only `proc(X)` is considered, and that matches, because the `z` you pass in is an `X`.

At runtime, polymorphism in Java means that the runtime of the object on which the method is called is taken into consideration for determining which override to call.  `Y`'s `proc` overrides `X`'s `proc`.  However, `Z`'s `proc` method takes a `Z`, not an `X`, so `Z`'s `proc` method *overloads* `proc`; it does *not* override it.  Therefore, `Y`'s `proc` is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are **not overriding** `proc` method but you are **overloading** it - that means that you are creating another method with the same name but different arguments list.

The most fitting method will be used.